# How to detect the 'service stop' command in Linux

Tags: c, linux, service

I'm writing a C application to drive a LED strip on a Linux machine: the application listens on a TCP socket port to receive commands.
If the connection is terminated, the application waits another connection.

I launch this application as service by a systemd configuration file, and it is running silently well.

The only problem is that when the machine restarts or shuts off (or simply I need to restart the service) the service drops any connection and delays the power down, waiting the socket timeout to goes on. I guess it is waiting for a new connection ..

Is there a way detect the 'service stop' command, just to avoid to fall in the 'wait for a connection' command and simply terminate the application?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "service" here? Do you mean a system service, managed by `init` or `systemd` or something like that? Or are you using that term in a different way? For a system service, the usual approach would be to provide the application with a clean-shutdown mechanism that the service manager can invoke. Then the application wouldn't have to be killed. Alternatively you could trap whatever signal the platform uses when you stop the service, and shut the application down in the signal handler. But, really, it's difficult, not knowing exactly what you mean by "service"

Comment: Thanks, I mean an application defined by a /etc/systemd/system/my.service file and controlled by systemctl command. When I run it on command line I press Ctrl-C twice to close it.

Comment: Have you provided a specific way for `systemd` to shut your service down? For example, have you specific a command for `ExecStop`? If you want a smooth and timely shutdown, `systemd` needs to know how to shut your service down. The actual implementation could be fiddly, however.

Comment: No, So far there is only ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rpirgb and ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

Comment: Well, you ask if there's a way to detect the service stop, and the simple answer is to implement `ExecStop`. But how? Crudely, you could have it do a `kill -9` on your service. Of course, you'd have to think carefully about whether that's safe. The nice way is to `ExecStart` a program that interacts with your service and shuts it down nicely. The interaction could be by a network socket, or a Unix socket, or sending a user signal that your service traps. The hard part is doing the clean shut-down itself, particularly if your application is stuck in an `accept()` call or something like that.

Comment: I will test the 'kill -9 $MAINPID'. The application already have a SIGINT and SIGTERM handler .. maybe should I handle other SIG?

Comment: If you're generating the signals yourself, you can use whatever you wish ;)